# jquery tools .onSuccess

Tags: jquery

Can someone point me in the right direction on this? I am using Tools as a validator but wanting to execute the ajax submit function that I have ONLY IF ALL validation passes. I have a working validation script here that works, and an ajax call that works; but I'm having a time trying to figure out how to get them to work together.

How can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leadbanker_intake_form").validator({ 
        position: 'center right',
        offset: [0, 0],
        message: '<div><em/></div>'
    }).bind("onSuccess", function(e, els) {
        // FUNCTION HERE still works even though some forms haven't validated
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/index.html):

> The second argument is a jQuery object containing all fields that passed the validation.

So, in your `onSuccess` callback, you just need to check the `length` of `els` (the second argument) and make sure it's equal to the total number of fields you're validating.

---

I think this should work (but I haven't tested it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leadbanker_intake_form").validator({ 
        position: 'center right',
        offset: [0, 0],
        message: '<div><em/></div>'
    }).bind("onSuccess", function(e, els) {
        var numSucceeded = els.length,
            numExpected = $(this).data('validator').getInputs().length;

        if (numSucceeded === numExpected) {
            // get your Ajax on
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Edit:** In your comment below, you said that if you use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leadbanker_intake_form").validator({ 
        position: 'center right',
        offset: [0, 0],
        message: '<div><em/></div>'
    }).bind("onSuccess", function(e, els) {
        var numSucceeded = els.length,
            numExpected = $(this).data('validator').getInputs().length;

        if (numSucceeded === numExpected) {
            $("#leadbanker_intake_form").submit(function() {}
        }
    }
});
```

then the code just seems to be ignored. I see two problems with that.

First, that code is syntactically incorrect - you're missing two close parens (the code on your question was already missing one, and I forgot to add that one in). To fix the syntax, that code should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leadbanker_intake_form").validator({ 
        position: 'center right',
        offset: [0, 0],
        message: '<div><em/></div>'
    }).bind("onSuccess", function(e, els) {
        var numSucceeded = els.length,
            numExpected = $(this).data('validator').getInputs().length;

        if (numSucceeded === numExpected) {
            $("#leadbanker_intake_form").submit(function() {}); // <-- here
        }
    }); // <-- and here
});
```

Note the semicolons you missed as well. I'm not sure if these syntax errors exist in the actual code you're trying to run, or if that was a transcription error on your part, but it's definitely a serious enough syntax error to break the whole thing.

The other problem is that `.submit(...)` call binds a submit listener, **if** the form validated. However - and I'm not sure of this part - your form may have already submitted by the time you bind that `submit` handler. The solution to that problem is to bind the listener outside of the `onSuccess` callback. The other possibility regarding this (I really need to read over the jQuery TOOLS docs...) is that you need to manually submit the form - that is, you might be successfully binding the handler, *but the form's never actually submitting*!

I really can't say much more without looking a the TOOLS docs, and maybe your actual code as well. If the suggestions in this edit don't fix the problem for you, would you mind posting a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: the problem i am having is that my ajax function $("#leadbanker_intake_form").submit(function() { // code } doesn't work for some reason.  If I put that statement outside of the scope of the validator then it works, but when it's inside the bind on the validator it doesn't do a thing and instead the page just does a normal post back and never executes the code inside submit function.

Comment: for exmaple, replacing your "// get your ajax on" with "$("#leadbanker_intake_form").submit(function() {}" does nothing and instead, i think it's just saying "hey i've succeeded in validating, and now i can see this nice ajax call, but i'm going to ignore it"

Comment: @Joe Smack: I played around with jQuery TOOLS a bit, and it looks like you don't need to bind your own form `submit` event handlers **at all**. Just do whatever logic you'd do in the `submit` handler, in the `// get your Ajax on` part. Does that make sense?